# Why internet is not working on internet explorer 8 in ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: ubuntu, internet-explorer, ubuntu-16.04, wine

I have installed IE-8 using wine-HQ but internet is not working on IE-8. Actually, there are some sites in my office who just open on Internet explorer.

**Solution on internet**

Use user agent on chrome and Mozilla.

I had also used different user agent on chromium and Mozilla as IE, but didn't work for me.

Please suggest me a solution.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Internet Explorer** was developed for Windows OS. So it works best with the Windows environment.

Internet Explorer is directly not supported on Ubuntu OS. So you are using the **Wine** software to install the **IE**.

But **IE** depend upon many things that are not available in Ubuntu OS. Which can crash IE or it can not work properly or work with very poor performance.

So even if you successfully installed it, there is no any guarantee that it will work properly.

This is the cause for your issue.

I suggest you to use the **virtual machine** and try to install any **Windows OS**. In that OS you can try to use the **Internet Explorer** without any issue.

I think this is the correct and suitable way to solve your issue with IE.

In Windows OS try to prefer IE 11 version which is latest one.

Comment: yeah you are right it crashes after some time and does not open any site other then msn.com But there should be a solution for Ubuntu to open IE restricted site.